# ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running after re-deploying rails 3.1.0 app on utuntu & nginx 1.0.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

The passenger (on ubuntu & nginx 1.0.6) is not running after re-deploying rails 3.1.0 app. The error is the same (ERROR:Phusion Passenger doesn't seems running) after executing "bundle vendors/gems".

```
   $ sudo passenger-status
    *** Phusion Passenger: no passenger_native_support.so found for the current Ruby interpreter. Compiling one...
    # mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/ruby/ruby-1.9.2-x86_64-linux
    # cd /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/ruby/ruby-1.9.2-x86_64-linux
    # /usr/local/bin/ruby '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/ruby/extconf.rb'
    checking for alloca.h... yes
    checking for ruby/io.h... yes
    checking for rb_reserved_fd_p()... no
    creating Makefile
    # make
    gcc -I. -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/ruby -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H -DHAVE_RUBY_IO_H    -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -g  -o passenger_native_support.o -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/ruby/passenger_native_support.c
    gcc -shared -o passenger_native_support.so passenger_native_support.o -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
    ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.
```

Any idea to fix the problem? thanks.

Comment: Re-installed passenger and found that openssl not installed for ruby. However in irb, require 'openssl' returns true. executing passenger-install-nginx-module always prompts 'openssl not installed for ruby'